# Cannot get blender carafe clean

Tags: cleaning, appliances

It's actually clean but it's cloudy.

I have found many things online, but none of them work:

- lemon/salt
- baking soda/vinegar
- vinegar soak

Sometimes it looks clear then it gets cloudy again.

I have a new dishwasher that has salt to soften the water. If that's what ruined this carafe, maybe I should just buy a new one ($110).

Of course, maybe the dishwasher is what ruined it and I should never put it in there?

Or maybe there's some other strategy I don't know about, hence my question.

Comment: If it was the dishwasher, you don't need a new one, you need to configure the amount of salt use in a washing cycle. If you use all-in-one tablets and regular salt, it's far too much because the tablets have salt integrated in them. The manual of your washer should tell you how to configure the salt amount.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/11153/6973

Comment: BTW, salt (table salt, NaCl) should *not** be used in a dishwasher. Separate *water softeners* use salt to exchange with calcium ions.

Comment: Is it just the appearance that bothers you, or do you think the carafe is having a detrimental effect on the taste ? If it's the appearance only, is it worth 110 dollars to you to change it? (Personally I wouldn't bother, as there is huge list of other stuff I'd rather spend on, but everyone is free to spend their money as they wish!)

Comment: Yeah I can think of a ton of ways I would rather spend $110. But I also get tired of looking at this thing that is sitting right next to my sink everyday that looks like dingy leftovers from a yard sale.

Comment: The dishwasher did not make it cloudy. My old dishwasher did not have salt, the new one (a Miele) does. It uses it very sparingly. My point was if the old one, using hard water, messed up the carafe, maybe a new carafe now that I have a softener, would stay clean.

Answer (score 3):

From your description, "actually clean but it's cloudy," it seems that the carafe is scratched or [crazed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazing) if it is plastic, or if it is glass, it is etched, [corroded](https://digitalfire.com/4sight/education/attack_on_glass_corrosion_attack_mechanisms_143.html) or covered with an adhering deposit, likely "lime" (calcium carbonate).

- If the carafe is scratched, corroded or crazed, there is no easy way to polish it, and it is likely to get damaged again even if it were polished.
- If the issue is buildup of lime, and vinegar has not removed it, you might try cleaners with [sulfamic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfamic_acid) or hydrochloric acid, available in many hardware stores and supermarkets. Use caution, as these can harm skin and damage eyes, as well as damaging metal trim and appliances.

You may *not* be able to restore the appearance of the carafe, but if it's clean and functional, that might be sufficient for continued use.

Answer (score 3):

The soda-lime glass commonly used for blender jars is susceptible to being surface-etched by food acids. This effect is sensitively dependent on the chemical composition of the glass, and it is possible to reveal manufacturing anisotropies via selective-area etching in the glass composition after years of use of the blender jar.

In the USA, it is common for the screw pitch and diameter of the impeller assembly that screws into the bottom of the jar to match that of so-called "Mason Jars" used for home-canning of food. This means you can substitute a large-size mason jar for the original blender jar if it gets broken or too badly etched into milkiness for your taste.

Answer (score 1):

I owned a restaurant and we had this problem. We would disassemble the carafe as much as possible. Ours would unscrew at the bottom and the blade mechanism and a gasket would come out.

We would wash everything first in hot water and dish soap. Then we would make a solution of highly chlorinated water (couple of capfuls of chlorine bleach in one gallon of water), and let everything soak overnight.